# Laravel Take integer value from string from database while querying

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have a field in database named experience and it has values like 5 Years or 2 Years etc.
Now I want to search all users having experience between 2 years to 5 years.
How can I do that?
How can I apply a range on string like 2 years.

Comment: DB::table('experience')->whereBetween(what you want)->get(); you can try wherebetween

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
  DB::table('experience')->where(function ($query) use ($YOURVARIABLE) {
        $query->where('2years', '<=', $YOURVARIABLE);
        $query->where('5years', '>=', $YOURVARIABLE);
    })->get();
```

Comment: but please can you tell me how it happens that a string is dealing like integer on comparison operator?

Comment: In the above case, I just checking an where condition using where condition it check the users between 2 to 5 years experience

Answer (score 0):

first of all take all values from data with the years, store them in a array.
than remove the the static 'Years' word from the string, you will get number,
than apply range query on it.
select * from YOURTABLE 
where YEAR_RANGE 'FIRST_VALUE' and 'SECOND_VALUE' 
order by YEARS desc;

Comment: but dont you think it will make query slow?